# SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Tags: python

Код:

```
def rotor_random_position(self, position, alphabet):
    self.position = [random.randrange(26), random.randrange(26), random.randrange(26)]
    print('Remeber:', self.position)

def r_up(self, pos_up):
    self.pos_up = [(self.position[0] + 1), (self.position[1] + 1), (self.position[2] + 1)]

def go_back(self, pos_up, position):
    if self.pos_up[0] > 26:
        self.position[0] = 1

    elif self.pos_up[1] > 26:
        self.position[1] = 1

    elif self.pos_up[2] > 26:
        self.position[2] = 1

    elif self.pos_up[0] and self.pos_up[1] > 26:
        self.position[0] and self.position[1] = 1

    elif self.pos_up[1] and self.pos_up[2] > 26:
        self.position[1] and self.position[2] = 1

    elif self.pos_up[0] and self.pos_up[2] > 26:
        self.position[0] and self.position[2] = 1
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, что если pos_up вдруг будет больше 26, то будет возвращать position равной 1, выводит SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Comment: Чего вы пытаетесь добиться этой строкой `self.position[0] and self.position[1] = 1` ?

Comment: Кстати да, тут не логично

Comment: Я хотел сделать, чтобы если pos_up > 26, то он возвращался к единице, то есть pos_up == 1

Comment: Спасибо, я уже справился